# display dynamic table using hydrb

Tags: android, flutter, dart, hybrid-mobile-app

I am facing an issue to displaying dynamic data. Please I need help. I want my table to look like the picture below. It return error `Exception: ErrorNoSuchMethodError: The getter 'iterator' was called on null.`

And I'm using hybrid dart and html

Pic **#1**

[image]

HTML code

```
<table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
   <thead style="background-color:#f6f6f6;">
      <tr style="height:40px;">
         <th style="text-align:center; font-family: arial;font-size: 14px;text-transform: uppercase;">
            Serial No.
         </th>
         <th style="text-align:center; font-family: arial;font-size: 14px;text-transform: uppercase;">
            Number.
         </th>
         <th style="text-align:center; font-family: arial;font-size: 14px;text-transform: uppercase;">
            A
         </th>
         <th style="text-align:center; font-family: arial;font-size: 14px;text-transform: uppercase;">
            B
         </th>
         <th style="text-align:center; font-family: arial;font-size: 14px;text-transform: uppercase;">
            C
         </th>
         <th style="text-align:center; font-family: arial;font-size: 14px;text-transform: uppercase;">
            D
         </th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="wallThickness">
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Dart code

```
wallThinknessHtml(
    List < Map < String, dynamic >> wallThinkness) {
    try {
        if (wallThinkness != null) {
            var wallThinknessHtml = "";
            var wallTick = transformData([wallThinkness]);
            for (var entry in wallTick) {
                var type = entry['type'].trim();
                if (type == 'Form - Serial No') {
                    for (var sheet in entry['value']) {
                        wallThinknesstHtml +=
                            '<tr><td style="font-size: 13px;font-family: Montserrat;text-align:center;">' +
                            sheet['serialNo'] +
                            '</td><td style="font-size: 13px;font-family: Montserrat;text-align:center;">' +
                            sheet['number'] +
                            '</td><td style="font-size: 13px;font-family: Montserrat;text-align:center;">' +
                            sheet['valueA'] +
                            '</td><td style="font-size: 13px;text-align:center;font-family: Montserrat;">' +
                            sheet['ValueB'] +
                            '</td><td style="font-size: 13px;text-align:center;font-family: Montserrat;">' +
                            sheet['ValueC'] +
                            '</p></td><td style="font-size: 13px;text-align:center;font-family: Montserrat;">' +
                            sheet['ValueD'] +
                            '</td></tr>';
                    }
                }
            }
            return wallThinknessHtml;
        } else {
            log("====*****wallThinknessHtml not found");
            return '';
        }
    } catch (e) {
        throw Exception("Error" + e.toString());
    }
}


List transformData(List wallTick) {
    wallTick.reduce((a, b) {
        int rows = b.keys.length - 1;
        b.keys.forEach((key) {
            if (key != 'serialNo') {
                var item = {
                    'serialNo': b['serialNo'],
                    'rowspan': b.keys.toList().indexOf(key) == 1 ? rows : 0,
                    'number': b.keys.toList().indexOf(key),
                    'valueA': b[key]['valueA'],
                    'valueB': b[key]['valueB'],
                    'valueC': b[key]['valueC'],
                    'valueD': b[key]['valueD'],
                };
                a.add(item);
            }
        });
        return a;
    });
}
```

JSON data

```
wallTick = [{
    serialNo: 'se01',
    v1: {
        valueA: 1.2,
        valueB: 1.2,
        valueC: 1.4,
        valueD: 1.5,
    },
    v2: {
        valueA: 1.6,
        valueB: 1.7,
        valueC: 1.8,
        valueD: 1.9,
    },
    v3: {
        valueA: 1.0,
        valueB: 2.1,
        valueC: 2.2,
        valueD: 2.3,
    },
    v4: {
        valueA: 2.4,
        valueB: 2.5,
        valueC: 2.6,
        valueD: 2.7,
    },
    v5: {
        valueA: 2.8,
        valueB: 2.9,
        valueC: 2.0,
        valueD: 3.0,
    },
    v6: {
        valueA: 3.1,
        valueB: 3.2,
        valueC: 3.3,
        valueD: 3.4,
    },
    v7: {
        valueA: 3.5,
        valueB: 3.6,
        valueC: 3.7,
        valueD: 3.8,
    },
    v8: {
        valueA: 3.9,
        valueB: 4.0,
        valueC: 4.1,
        valueD: 4.2,
    },
}];
```

Thanks in advance..

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.